# How to get the number of continuous increase data point in Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, optimization, pandas, while-loop, cpu-cache

Thanks for your help in advance!
I have one dataframe. say, for colume incr, the number if 0 1 1 1 -1 0 1 1 ...., I would like to get parse the list and get for each datapoint, how many times the data list had increased (or more exactly not decreased); decrease in the point would reset the output into zero for the current data point.  for example for the list (named output['inc_adj'] in the code )
0 1 1 1 -1 0 1 -1
I should get named output['cont_inc'] in the code
1 2 3 4  0 1 2  0

I wrote the following code, but it is very inefficient, any suggestion for improve the efficiency significantly, please? It seemed that I am keeping reloading the cache in CPU among the two loops(if my feeling is correct), but I could not find a better solution at the current stage.

> ```
> output['cont_inc']=0;
> for i in xrange(1,output['inc_adj'].count()):
>     j=i;
>     while(output['inc_adj'][j] != -1):
>           #for both increase or unchanged
>         output['cont_inc'][i]+=1;
>         j-=1
> ```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

If memory allows, I would suggest building a list with all the adjacent values for comparison to start with (in my sample using **zip**), and append the result to a new list, re-assign the whole result list back to the DataFrame after completion.

Although it sounds odd, but in reality it improves the performance a little by eliminating a little overhead of constant DataFrame index/value lookup:

```
import pandas as pd
import random

# random DataFrame with values from -1 to 2
df = pd.DataFrame([random.randint(-1, 2) for _ in xrange(999)], columns=['inc_adj'])
df['cont_inc'] = 0

def calc_inc(df):
    inc = [1]
    # I use zip to PREPARE the adjacent values
    for i, n in enumerate(zip(df['inc_adj'][1:], df['inc_adj'][:-1]), 0):
        if n[0] >= n[1]:
            inc.append(inc[i]+1)
            continue
        inc.append(0)
    df['cont_inc'] = inc
```

---

```
calc_inc(df)

df.head()
   inc_adj  cont_inc
0        0         1
1        0         2
2        1         3
3       -1         0
4        0         1

%timeit calc_inc(df)
1000 loops, best of 3: 696 µs per loop
```

As a comparison, using indexing and/or lookup and in-place assignment, similarly coding logic:

```
def calc_inc_using_ix(df):
    for idx, row in df.iterrows():
        try:
            if row['inc_adj'] >= df['inc_adj'][idx-1]:
                row['cont_inc'] = df['cont_inc'][idx-1] + 1
                continue
            row['cont_inc'] = 0
        except KeyError:
            row['cont_inc'] = 1
```

---

```
calc_inc_using_ix(df)

df.head()
   inc_adj  cont_inc
0        0         1
1        1         2
2        1         3
3        0         0
4        2         1

%timeit calc_inc_using_ix(df)
10 loops, best of 3: 58.5 ms per loop
```

That said, I'm also interested in any other solutions that will further improve the performance, always willing to learn.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help. It solved my problem with a much better performance. I may cut the whole list into parts to fit the memory for large datasets. Your help is really appreciated!

Comment: @Tsigalko2003, not a problem, I'm also keen on seeing performance and efficiency :)